# No Cookies at second Webrequest

Tags: c#, cookies, authentication, webrequest

I login to a website by HTTPwebrequest, I get an authentication cookie.

When I make a new HTTP-webrequest and add the cookies from the first request to call the next page where I can see my personal data. I see that the cookies will associated with the second request if I debug it but if I check the network traffic I see that are no Cookies transmitted at the second request. I tried many possibilities to see why I don't work but I found nothing.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can you add a code example of how you are doing the two requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WebRequest using Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158448/c-sharp-webrequest-using-cookies)