# Crawling https websites which are forms authentication based

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi i am able to crawl http websites which are not secured using html agility packs. But some websites which are https secured will requires authentication(probably forms authentication) to see its contents hence i am unable to crawl. I saw IBMs omnifind crawler plug can we use this for .net.  Can u guys please hint on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You will obviously need credentials, so you should sort out how the authentication bits are working.

Assuming it's forms-based, you shouldn't have any trouble implementing something with a CookieContainer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx)

The sample at the bottom of that link shows how to iterate over the cookies that are returned from a site.

And here's an existing question that should help direct you as well: [WebRequest class to post data to login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260080/webrequest-class-to-post-data-to-login-form)

Cheers.